# PyQt5 - Position a widget at top right corner of a QTextEdit

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtextedit

I'm developping a text editor with pyqt5 and I want to implement a Find Box which  sticks to the top right corner of my textarea just like this:

image

[image]

```
textarea = QTextEdit()
layout = QHBoxLayout() # tried hbox, vbox and grid
find_box = QLineEdit()
empty = QTabWidget()
layout.addWidget(empty)
layout.addWidget(empty)
layout.addWidget(find_box)
textarea.setLayout(layout)
```

So with this code, I managed to have my Find Box stick to the left of my texarea, even when window gets resized. But somehow the y position of my textarea's layout starts from the middle:

image

[image]

An awful solution is to set the textarea as my Find Box parent, use move(x, y) to set the Find Box's position but I'll have to catch whenever my window or my textarea get resized and use move() again to set a new position.

So why my QTextEdit's layout starts from the middle? And is there anyway to avoid this?

Comment: it's a simpler version for demonstrating. I've created some personnal classes for textarea and find box so it would be confusing and useless to put all the code here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it working by using a `gridlayout` and setting stretch factors to rows and columns.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys

class Wind(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUI()

    def setupUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(300,300, 300,500)
        self.show()
        text_area= QTextEdit()
        find_box = QLineEdit()

        # this layout is not of interest
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(text_area)

        # set a grid layout put stuff on the text area
        self.setLayout(layout)

        text_layout= QGridLayout()

        # put find box in the top right cell (in a 2 by 2 grid) 
        text_layout.addWidget(find_box, 0, 1)

        # set stretch factors to 2nd row and 1st column so they push the find box to the top right
        text_layout.setColumnStretch(0, 1)
        text_layout.setRowStretch(1, 1)

        text_area.setLayout(text_layout)


def main():
    app= QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Wind()
    exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```